# Data Table and css styling

Tags: html, css

Hello i got some data from db and i want to display it using table

First question: should i use  or div styled in css ?

Second Question: If i'm using Talbe , i got one col with few lines of text , the lines may be long
how can i style one col to be with a fixed size of the table (like 20%)?

Third : i'm looking for a good link that explain how to design tables the smart way considering cross browser resolution with changing text , (i.e using em ?)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If it's tabular data (columns and more than one row) you'll find it much easier to do with a table. Style the table with css which will let you fix the size of the 'text' column.

Using em for sizing is the best option in my opinion.

Comment: it's  tabular data , is there a complete guide for styling css for table ?

Comment: The W3Schools guide covers the basics [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp). They don't mention <caption> which I think is the least used table tag that should be used more often instead of colspan in the first row !

Comment: I should have added that JSFiddle.net [link](http://jsfiddle.net) is great for trying stuff out regarding formatting.

Answer (score 0):

**One**
If you are displaying tabular information that makes sense in rows and columns then YES use a table.

**Two**
Set the column widths using width="20%" will make it a fixed size

**Three**
For font-sizes use EM  for widths use percentages that way it will work with an resolution screen and obey the users default font size.

Answer (score 0):

1. If data preview, better is just a table (displaying tabular information)
2. `<td width="200"` … as your wish you can give the value, for other column dont specify any value.
3. http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/